# How to make purely client side shopping cart calculation in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[image]

Above is my shopping cart. Below I show the flow.

> [product image clicked] -> ajax request fetches details from database
>   for that particular product id and appends (product name,id and price
>   automatically appended) via jquery.
>
> [onfocus QTY] -> jquery autocalculates sub total and displays ->
>
> also sends ajax request to calculate total,gst and total payment and
>   this is where the problem begins.
>
> Since the ajax request made onfocus, each time QTY textfield is
>   focused, it goes to the php page and make calculation for total,gst
>   and total payment thus the amount keep increasing beyond logic.

I save all values that passed to the php page in session. So each time,ajax request carries qty and sub total values it keeps adding to the session. To save the hassle, I would like to try out purely client side calculation for the white area just like how I calculate sub total without making ajax request.

Whats the way, can somebody give me idea on how to add total quantity and total sub_total for all items without having to send to PHP page for the calculation? Maybe can introduce to me jQuery array sort of thing please. I tried searching online but couldn't understand.

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="cart_form">
<table class='header_tbl' style="background:none !important;">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Sub Total</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

    <tr>
    <td>Total</td><td></td><td><span class='qty_1'></span><input type='hidden' name='total_qty' value=''></td><td><span class='total'></span><input type='hidden' name='total' value=''></td><td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>GST 6%</td><td></td><td></td><td><span class='gst'></span><input type='hidden' name='gst' value=''></td><td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Discount (x%)</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Total Payment</td><td></td><td></td><td><span class='grand'></span><input type='hidden' name='grand' value=''></td><td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan="5" class="checkout"><input type="submit" name='submit' id="checkout" value="CHECK OUT"/></td></tr>
    </tfoot>



</table>
 </form>
```

Script to append elements into form

```
 for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $(".header_tbl tbody").prepend("<tr id='"+data[i].id+"'><th class='product'>"+data[i].catalog_name+"<input type='hidden' name='catalog_name[]' value='"+data[i].catalog_name+"'></th><td class='price'>RM <span>"+data[i].price_normal+"</span><input type='hidden' name='"+data[i].id+"_price[]' value='"+data[i].price_normal+"'></td><td class='qty_"+data[i].id+"'><input type='text' name='qty' style='width:50px;height:20px;margin:10px auto;' onfocus='subTotal(\""+data[i].id+"\")' value=''><input type='hidden' name='"+data[i].id+"_qty2[]' value=''></td><td class='sub_total'><span class='sub_total_"+data[i].id+"'></span><input type='hidden' name='"+data[i].id+"_sub_total[]' value=''></td><td><img src='"+p_img_path+"del.png' style='width:15px;cursor:pointer;' onClick='del_this(\""+data[i].id+"\")'></td></tr>");  
                      }
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching an onchange event to your quanity boxes to do the calculation then the event is fired?

Comment: since the qty & price of every product is present at the client side inside DOM itself, you can calculate at client side itself using jquery. post your DOM structure here

Comment: @dreamweiver, i added my html and script in my post

Comment: @Bindrid, I simply replaced onfocus with onchange and that calculation problem is solved for me. However you have any idea about client side calculation without having to fire the event, or is it possible?

Comment: Why would you not want to use an onchange event?  The overhead is trival in the would of client side programing?

Comment: @Bindrid, I would use onchange event. Just for my knowledge, would like to manage from client side rather than server side and  that would improvise the performance in the long run.

Comment: Now I am confused. An onchange event is a client side event, though I would have done it differently than you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is my approach:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {    

    $(document).on("input paste keyup", ".product_qty", function( event ) {         
        
        var product_quantity = 0;
        var product_price = 0;
        var gst_amount = 0;

        var sub_total = 0;
        var total_qty = 0; 
        var grand_total = 0

        product_quantity = $(this).val();
        product_price = $(this).parent().prev().html();

        sub_total = product_price * product_quantity;

        $(this).parent().next().html(sub_total);


        $('.product_qty' ).each( function( k, v ) {
            product_quantity = parseInt ( $(this).val() ) ? parseInt ( $(this).val() ) : 0;
            product_price = parseFloat($(this).parent().prev().html())?parseFloat($(this).parent().prev().html()):0;

            console.log(product_quantity);
            console.log(product_price);            

            sub_total = parseFloat ( product_price * product_quantity );

            console.log(sub_total);

            total_qty +=product_quantity;

            grand_total += sub_total;

        });

        if ( grand_total > 0 ){
            gst_amount = ( grand_total * 6 ) /100;
        }
         
        $("#total_qty").html(total_qty);        
        $("#total_amount").html(grand_total);        

        grand_total +=gst_amount;

        $("#gst_amount").html(gst_amount);        
        $("#discount_amount").html(0);        
        $("#grand_total").html(grand_total);  
      
    });
    //
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function( event ) {
        
        var cart_item = 0;
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        cart_item = $('.product_qty').length;
        if ( cart_item <= 0 ) 
        {
            $("#total_qty").html('0');        
            $("#total_amount").html('0');        
            $("#gst_amount").html('0');        
            $("#discount_amount").html(0);        
            $("#grand_total").html('0');             
        } else {
            $('.product_qty').trigger('keyup');  
        }      
        
    }); 
    
    
});
// End Document Ready
```

```css
    .bs-example{
        background: #355979;
        margin: 20px;
    }
    a {
        color:#FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    table{
        color:#FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    table input{
        color:#000;
    }
    .delete{
        color:#E13D3D;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .checkout{
        background: #FF002A;
    }
    .checkout a{
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="table-responsive"> 
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="con1" style="align: center; width: 30%" />
                <col class="con1" style="align: center; width: 20%" />
                <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 20%" />
                <col class="con1" style="align: center; width: 20%" />
                <col class="con1" style="align: center; width: 10%" />
            </colgroup>           
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Sub Total</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Karpap Pushing Ayu</td>
                    <td class="product_price">5</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="product_qty" value="5"></td>
                    <td class="amount_sub_total">25</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="delete">x</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Slimming Tea</td>
                    <td class="product_price">25</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="product_qty" value="5"></td>
                    <td class="amount_sub_total">125</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="delete">x</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tudung Shawl Butterfly</td>
                    <td class="product_price">15</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="product_qty" value="3"></td>
                    <td class="amount_sub_total">45</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="delete">x</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tudung Shawl Butterfly 5</td>
                    <td class="product_price">20</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="product_qty" value="2"></td>
                    <td class="amount_sub_total">40</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="delete">x</a></td>
                </tr> 

                <tr>
                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="total_qty">15</td>
                    <td id="total_amount">235</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>GST 6 %</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="gst_amount">14.1</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Discount  (x%)</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="discount_amount">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Payment</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="grand_total">249.1</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="checkout"><a href="#">CHECKOUT</a></td>
                </tr>                                             
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

you have to change this as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM structure for the product would look something like this

**HTML CODE:**

```
<table class='header_tbl'>
 <tr>
   <th>Product</th>
   <th>Price</th>
   <th>Qty</th>
   <th>Sub Total</th>
 </tr>
 <tr class="product_details">
   <td class="product">T-shirt</td>
   <td class="price">
     <input type='text' name='grand' value='300' />
   </td>
   <td class="qty">
     <input type='text' name='grand' value='3' />
   </td>
   <td class="subtotal">
     <input type='text' name='grand' value='' />
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The change handler for calculating the cost may look like this

**JS CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.header_tbl').on('change', '.price, .qty', function() {
     var pr_price = $(this).closest('.product_details').find('.price input').val();
     var qty = $(this).closest('.product_details').find('.qty input').val();
     var sub_total = pr_price * qty;

     $(this).closest('.product_details').find('.subtotal input').val(sub_total);
  });
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/xnvqa74y/1/)

*Note:The above code/DOM structure is just for illustration of the client side calculation, so dont consider it as a final solution.*